# ValidationException on aws_lambda_event_source_mapping

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In an attempt to bring up a DynamoDb-triggered lambda, I'm constantly receiving this error:

```
Error: error creating Lambda Event Source Mapping (): ValidationException:
        status code: 400, request id: 2e09272b-68e5-4713-b083-c95db9dbad6e

  on dynamo.tf line 30, in resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "dynamodb_lambda_mapping":
  30: resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "dynamodb_lambda_mapping" {
```

And can't figure out what is it saying or how to debug it. That's the code:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "connections_dynamodb_table" {
name           = "tf-connections"
billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
hash_key       = "connectionId"
read_capacity  = 5
write_capacity = 5

attribute {
    name = "connectionId"
    type = "S"
}
}


data "archive_file" "dynamodb_triggered_lambda_code" {
type        = "zip"
source_dir  = "dynamodb_triggered_lambda_code"
output_path = "dynamodb_triggered_lambda_zipped_code.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "dynamodb_triggered_lambda" {
function_name    = "tf_test_dynamodb_triggered_lambda"
role             = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
handler          = "index.handler"
source_code_hash = data.archive_file.dynamodb_triggered_lambda_code.output_base64sha256
filename         = "dynamodb_triggered_lambda_zipped_code.zip"
runtime          = "nodejs14.x"
}

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "dynamodb_lambda_mapping" {
event_source_arn  = aws_dynamodb_table.connections_dynamodb_table.stream_arn
function_name     = aws_lambda_function.dynamodb_triggered_lambda.arn
starting_position = "LATEST"
}
```

The `aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda` resource is in another file in same directory. I ommitted it for sake of brevity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **enable streams** for your table:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "connections_dynamodb_table" {
  name           = "tf-connections"
  billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
  hash_key       = "connectionId"

  stream_enabled = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"

  read_capacity  = 5
  write_capacity = 5

  attribute {
      name = "connectionId"
      type = "S"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same error message and error status code.
In my case, I was using the wrong lambda arn from the output of this terraform module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest

You should use the `lambda_function_arn` output from this module.